# Intra-page link starts at URL root

Tags: anchor, accessibility

This is so simple I don't get how it could possibly go wrong. I'm trying to get a simple intra-page link to behave.

(If it's relevant, this is an angular 2 app, using routing.)

Here is a typical page:

```
<a href="#content-start">Skip to main content</a>

<div class="page-body">
    <main>
        <div class="content-body" id="content-start">
            <h1>Employee Search</h1>
        </div>
    <main>
</div>
```

The URL of this page (in my dev env) is

```
http://localhost:49974/app/employee/search
```

When I click (or focus then press enter) on **Skip to main content** it should go to

```
http://localhost:49974/app/employee/search#content-start
```

but instead goes to

```
http://localhost:49974/app#content-start
```

(and then immediately switches to

```
http://localhost:49974/app/#content-start
```

)

I can't have messed up the linking itself; this must have something to do with how the routing is working.

It looks like I *have* to do it this way:

```
<a href="app/request/timeoff#content-start">
```

But that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Does the page have a `base` element?

Comment: Can you add the tag 'angular' to the question? The system does not allow me do to this without also significantly editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a the correct way, or the angular way, but it works:

app.component.html:

```
<a href="{{pageURL}}#content-start">Skip to main content</a>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

    pageURL: string;

    ngDoCheck() {
        this.pageURL = window.location.href;
        var link = this.pageURL.indexOf('#content-start');
        if (link > -1) {
            console.log(this.pageURL.substring(0, link));
            this.pageURL = this.pageURL.substring(0, link);
        }
    }
}
```

every-page.html:

```
<h1 class="content-body" id="content-start">Page</h1>
```

Not sure if ngDoCheck is the appropriate event use.

Full disclosure: app.component is a wrapper - with header and the 'skip to content' link that contains all the pages and their content.

So, the logic for the 'skip to content' link exists once, while the actual content target #content-start lives in the top of each content page.